# pymongo returns less fields

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have a following problem. Pymongo returns less fields than it should.

Here is my query:
 `db.users.findOne({'e.email': 'xxx@gmail.com', application: 'App1'})`

Directly from mongo db I get:
`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51803128e4b092fd00c8899b"),
    "application": "App1",
    "d" : ISODate("2013-04-30T21:01:28.084Z"),
    "e" : [
        {
            "email" : "xxx@gmail.com",
            "isValidated" : true
        }
    ],
    "fn" : "XXX",
    "l" : "en_US",
    "ln" : YYY",
    "si" : [
        {
            "isTokenExpired" : true,
            "oAuth" : {
                "value" : "",
                "permissions" : [ ]
            },
            "sIden" : {
                "id" : "123",
                "network" : 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "tz" : "Etc/UTC"
}`

But pymongo doesn't return "si" array on the same query and fields ln,fn are empty:

`query = collection.find_one({'e.email': 'xxx@gmail.com', application: 'App1'})

print query`

`[{u'application': 'App1', u'tz': u'Etc/UTC', u'd': datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 30, 22, 52, 45, 916000), u'ln': u'', u'l': u'en_US', u'e': [{u'isValidated': True, u'email': u'xxx@gmail.com'}],u'_id': ObjectId('51804b3de4b092fd00c88d1b'), u'fn': u''}]`

What the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Could you check if there are more than 1 document satisfying this query criteria. If you observe the _id field in both the results are different. Also the 'd' parameter is different. So in all probability they both are not fetching the same document.

Comment: There is only one document like this. There couldn't be 2 identical emails for one app. But I also tried find instead of find_one and checked that there is only one.

Comment: Even the "ln" field does not match. Could you create some dummy document and test?

Comment: just tried with different email, got everything. So strange...

Comment: actually, my script is creating document and then I'm checking that we got proper info. In Mongo everything is perfect...

Comment: OMG! I got it! The problem is that I was checking too fast. Generation of 'si' was still in process! Thanks Nipun =)

Answer (score 1):

In PyMongo you are calling **findOne**, which will return only 1 document. Whereas when you are natively querying MongoDB, you are not calling findOne and thus getting more results. From your results it is apparent you are using **find()** for natively making the query.
Here is the difference between **findOne** and **find** as per official MongoDB [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/).

```
findOne()
One document that satisfies the query specified as the argument 
to this method. If the projection argument is specified, the 
returned document contains only the projection fields, and the _id
field if you do not explicitly exclude the _id field.

find()
A cursor to the documents that match the query criteria. 
If the projection argument is specified, the matching
documents contain only the projection fields, and the _id
field if you do not explicitly exclude the _id field.
```

Comment: Sorry Nipun, You answered different question. It's my misstake. I was telling about missed fields, not documents. I'll edit my question.